# How can I perform a reverse lookup type deal in MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Firstly I'd like to apologise if it's hard to understand what I'm getting at, I'm trying my best to explain the best I can.

OK, so this is the code I have to search the DB

```
require_once 'connect.php';
        if(isset($_GET['lookfor'])) {
            $keywords = $db->escape_string($_GET['lookfor']);
            $keywords = preg_replace("#[^0-9 a-z]-#i","",$keywords);
            $query = $db->query("
                SELECT *
                FROM lookup
                WHERE keywords LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
                OR title LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
            ");
```

But obviously that would just return matches to what I searched. What I want to achieve is for when I search for something say **'title'** what I want it to do is look at the keywords associated with that title and return from the database every other item that has the same keywords regardless of the title if that makes sense.

I have no idea how to do this as I'm new to learning. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: you are semi-vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). once you've escaped a string for sql usage, you should **NOT** be mangling that string - your regex is REMOVING the escape characters that the `escape_string()` would have added. and what you want is a join. main table -> keywords -> main table (aliased) to get alternate records using the same keywords.

Comment: From what I'm understanding you want to look up the keywords associated with the title and use that output to find different items which have (exactly?) the same keywords?

Comment: Yeah I'm looking to match with different items that have exactly the same keywords :)

Comment: Should I remove the 'preg_replace' line?

Comment: You should escape after your preg_replace. Also, did I answer your question? :)

Comment: @Seph For some reason when I did that I return 0 results even though I made sure that I had the same keywords in the DB.

Comment: @seph I got it to work :) Thank you for your help! I tried to mark your answer up but it wouldn't let me :( . Also thanks Mark B I will fix that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either use a [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html) or a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). To get the keywords from your title you'll need a query like:

```
SELECT keywords FROM lookup WHERE title LIKE ?
```

now you can use that output to find new titles, for this example I'll use a subquery.

```
SELECT titles FROM lookup WHERE keywords = 
  (SELECT keywords FROM lookup WHERE title LIKE ?)
```

Of course this will also return the original title and will only find titles that match exactly the same keywords.

Also as Marc B pointed out you're vulnerable to sql injection. You should first use your preg_replace and escape afterwards. But better yet use prepared statements from for example the [PDO library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PHP array_reverse() Function**\

```
<?php
$a=array("a"=>"Volvo","b"=>"BMW","c"=>"Toyota");
print_r(array_reverse($a));
?>
```